# How to optimize euclidian algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

I need to calculate euclidian distance for every point in matrix and store it into the List. But it works too slow. How can I get it faster?

```
public static char[,] fields = new char[10000, 10000]; // it contains different count of 't' and 'r' symbols
List<Tuple<int, int, double>> tuples = new List<Tuple<int, int, double>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < 10000; r++)
            {
                if (fields[i, r] != 't')
                    tuples.Add(Tuple.Create(i, r, Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(i - x, 2) + Math.Pow(r - y, 2))));
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can probably cut your execution time in half if the distance from point `a` to point `b` is the same as from `b` to `a` (which is usually, but not always the case)

Comment: Could you please show the example for my code? @AvrohomYisroel

Comment: Not offhand, because I'm not in front of my PC, but noting that when you add a tuple for `i` and `r`, you can add a tuples for `r` and `i` should get you there. You need to modify your loop limits so that you don't compute the distance for cases you've already handled.

Comment: You should profile, but it seems possible that the bulk of time may be spent resizing `tuples` and not actually calculating the values. If that's the case you may want to count the number of `t`s up front and size (pre-allocate) `tuples` accordingly before the loops. (I agree with Avrohom's observation too).

Comment: Of course it will be slow. 10000 * 10000 = 100 million iterations! But as I see, you need to find chars that are not `t` among 100 million chars. The loop is necessary — but iterating over such a big number of elements will be slow. I think your question has no answer.

Comment: And just continuing on from SNBS comment 100 million iterations is bad but an sqrt and 2 power operations is also Computational heavy instructions to do by the millions

Comment: You know the size of the list before you start loops so initialize it with the size. Also, don't compute the square root - it is very slow. The chances are you just need to find the closest point or compare against another distance - you can compute a square much faster than a square root.

Comment: Adding 100m items to a list is also slow. There's no way a user is going to scroll through 100m results, so what are you using the results for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pre-calculate each of the squares, so each squaring calculation is performed 10000 times instead of 10000*10000 times.

```
public static double[] preCalcSquares(int n) {
    double[] pre=new double[10000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        pre[i]=(i-n)*(i-n);
    }
    return pre;
}

. . .
double[] xSquares=preCalcSquares(x);
double[] ySquares=preCalcSquares(y);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < 10000; r++)
    {
        if (fields[i, r] != 't')
            tuples.Add(Tuple.Create(i, r, Math.Sqrt(xSquares[i] + ySquares[r])));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is another hint which might help - use specific squared function instead of generic Pow

```
double Squared(int x) => (double)(x*x);
```

so code would be

```
Math.Sqrt(Squared(i - x) + Squared(r - y))
```

And another optimization might be realized if your use of the result might be converted to dealing with distance squared. E.g.
comparison far/near could be easily done with distance squared. Then, you could save on computing square root of distance squared.

UPDATE

You could save one conversion operation if you do Squared all integers and convert to doubles later just before taking square root

Along the lines

```
int Squared(int x) => (x*x);
```

and

```
Math.Sqrt((double)(Squared(i - x) + Squared(r - y)));
```

Comment: You mean to change 'Math.Sqrt' to 'Squared' as well?

Comment: @Sneikso34 No, I mean remove or postpone Sqrt calculation if not necessary now. E.g. if you do mostly comparisons, r_i > r_j or other way around, you don't need Sqrt, it will work for r^2_i > r^2_j as well. Sqrt is monotonical function, it won't change ordering